# How to delete two rows together with foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I have two tables and these two have relationship like

```
class Lesson
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;



class TicketUse  
{
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Lesson")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lessonId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */

private $lessonId;
```

These two tables relation ships are.

If a row in Lesson is exist,a row in ticketUse exists or doesn't exist.

If a row in ticketUse exists which always has combination with a row in Lesson.

When I try to delete Lesson row 'DELETE FROM Lesson WHERE id = 1'

it shows error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I want to delete TicketUse automatically,when I delete Lesson.

Is there good way to delete both together?

I have two write delete sentences for each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for your *FOREIGN KEY* relationship, add ON *UPDATE CASCADE*.
then you will be able to delete according to your needs.
When you will delete the parent the change will be automatically reflected to the child.